# Which one is better for performance: foreach()tatement or Where() query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of elements and I want to filter the elements into otherlist based on specific condition. I have two options for that:

1. Use foreach() statement

   ```
       List<Address> allAddress = new List<Address>();
       List<Address> chaplinAddress = new List<Address>();

       foreach (Address item in allAddress)
       {
           if (item.city.ToUpper() == "CHAPLIN")
           {
               chaplinAddress.Add(item);
           }
       }
   ```
2. Using Where() clause

   ```
       List<Address> allAddress = new List<Address>();
       List<Address> chaplinAddress = new List<Address>();

       chaplinAddress = allAddress.Where(p => p.city.ToUpper() == "CHAPLIN").ToList();
   ```

Which of the above method is better for performance?

I looked for how Where() is executed on the below link but I am still not clear on that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx

Comment: You can check it out yourself using a timer object

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Actually what I was looking for is better performance.

Comment: Wouldn't better performance just be a different way of saying 'which is faster?'

Regardless, this one is easy - check it yourself.

Comment: Why are you asking us to [race your horses for you](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Comment: I think this is the definition of premature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ uses loops internally anyway... You can check how it works internally using [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/):

**`Enumerable.Where`**

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    if (source is Iterator<TSource>) return ((Iterator<TSource>)source).Where(predicate);
    if (source is TSource[]) return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate);
    if (source is List<TSource>) return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
    return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
}
```

**`Enumerable.ToList`**:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

and [**`WhereListIterator`**](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#208) (as a link, because it's a little to long to paste here...

There is a little overhead when you use LINQ, because of delegates invocation, but **you should not care about that at all**. Premature optimization like that is evil, and it's even worse then this tiny little amount of time overhead it requires.

Answer (score 2):

Decided to test this out. 1,000,000,000 random strings, with one "CHAPLIN" inserted.

- a foreach loop took 6 ticks.
- the LINQ query took 296 ticks.

Looks like foreach is faster.

Edit: did a more scientific study. Ran each test 1000 times, outside of VS, in release mode.

- a for each loop averaged at 0 ticks.
- lima query averaged at 4 ticks.

Keep in mind a tick is one ten-millionth of a second, which makes the difference 0.0000004 seconds, for 1000 lookups of 1,000,000,000 cities.

I think you're good man.

Comment: There is something wrong with you benchmark. `10000000` ints from `0` to `9999999`, foreach vs LINQ `Where`+`ToList` to get only these for which `i % 10 == 0`. Results? `foreach`: 284ms, LINQ: 379ms. Release build, run outside the VS.

Comment: I think its important to realize that no matter how many times I run this, its not going to be consistent.

Comment: Do you build as Release and run outside the IDE?

Comment: For instance, I pushed the different options into their own (identical) methods, and now I get 998,903, LINQ. Next time, 1176,910,LINQ. just ran a release build outside of VS, 1308, 8458, LINQ. next time, 2441, 15953, LINQ

Comment: Now, these are TICKS. I have doubts on whether this is significant in the OP's scenario. definitely premature optimization

Comment: Just optimized it a bit (timed just the needed code, not the method call), in release, outside of VS. ran each test 1000 times. Result: for each average was 0 ticks. Linq average was 4 ticks.

Comment: @Mike: I appreciate you took time to analyze this.

Comment: Important key here, don't prematurely optimize. Write your code for you, then profile, then optimize

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer object to check which one is faster but generally LINQ are not faster than foreach() as it(LINQ statements) also uses loops internally. On a side note it is to mention that LINQ is much easier to read, understand & lends itself to fewer bugs. But you should not use LINQ if you care much about performance

You may check [LINQ vs FOREACH vs FOR Loop Performance](http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html)

Comment: "But you should not use LINQ if you care much about performance" Err what? A case of premature optimization if I've ever seen one, unless this is in a tight loop or other performance hotspot I'd see LINQ as a non-issue

Comment: @jdphenix:- May be you got it wrong what I am trying to say is that LINQ is slower, and this is due to over head. Although LINQ is easier to read and maintain.